# How to make a DISTINCT CONCAT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

New SQL developer here, how do I make a `DISTINCT` `CONCAT` statement?

Here is my statement without the `DISTINCT` key:

```
COLUMN Employee FORMAT a25;
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(EMPLOYEEFNAME, ' '), EMPLOYEELNAME) AS "Employee", JOBTITLE "Job Title" 
FROM Employee
ORDER BY EMPLOYEEFNAME;
```

Here is it's output:

```
Employee                  Job Title               
------------------------- -------------------------
Bill Murray               Cable Installer          
Bill Murray               Cable Installer          
Bob Smith                 Project Manager          
Bob Smith                 Project Manager          
Frank Herbert             Network Specilist        
Henry Jones               Technical Support        
Homer Simpson             Programmer               
Jane Doe                  Programmer               
Jane Doe                  Programmer               
Jane Doe                  Programmer               
Jane Fonda                Project Manager          
John Jameson              Cable Installer          
John Jameson              Cable Installer          
John Carpenter            Technical Support        
John Carpenter            Technical Support        
John Jameson              Cable Installer          
John Carpenter            Technical Support        
John Carpenter            Technical Support        
Kathy Smith               Network Specilist        
Mary Jane                 Project Manager          
Mary Jane                 Project Manager          

 21 rows selected
```

If I were to use the `DISTINCT` key I should only have 11 rows selected, however
if I use `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT` I get an error.

Comment: Do `SELECT DISTINCT ... ORDER BY "Employee"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(EMPLOYEEFNAME, ' '), EMPLOYEELNAME) AS "Employee",
       JOBTITLE AS "Job Title" 
FROM Employee
GROUP BY CONCAT(CONCAT(EMPLOYEEFNAME, ' '), EMPLOYEELNAME),
         JOBTITLE
ORDER BY "Employee"
```

Another option, if you really want to use `DISTINCT`, would be to subquery your current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Employee,
                t."Job Title"
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(EMPLOYEEFNAME, ' '), EMPLOYEELNAME) AS "Employee",
           JOBTITLE AS "Job Title" 
    FROM Employee
) t
```

Comment: Can you explain the error the OP sees with `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: As for the first option, I tried to use `ORDER BY` with the `GROUP BY` however I now get a different error. `GROUP BY` does what I want it to do which is great, however I want to order the names by `ASC` order.

Comment: I can. When SELECT DISTINCT, only SELECT list items can be used in the ORDER BY.

Comment: Consider ('a','bcd'), ('abc','d'), ('ab','cd'). Same concatenated value, so you can't order by 1st item.